# How to combine a query of the LINQ and a list?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

[Sorry if it is a duplicate] 
I couldn't find properly solution, so I decided to ask a question.

I have an object `companies` which returns list of elements.

I would like to write a query which will select these all `CompanyId` which we have in our list. I don't want to select only one record by using `FirstOrDefault()`.

**Example:**

```
var companiesSummary = _context.Company
                       .Where(c => c.CompanyId == companies.Select(cs => cs.ID))
                       .Include(country => country.Country)
```

How can I cope with it? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried it the other way round? e.g.; `from c in companies... etc.`?

Comment: do you want to query all the Companies where there `id` is in `companies.Select(cs => cs.ID)` or ?

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers. @Stefan in my case it will not give the expected result.

Comment: Yes @Aominè, all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the ids of the companies from your in-memory list and then pass that into the query in the where method:

```
var ids = companies.Select(cs => cs.ID).ToList();
var companiesSummary = 
    _context.Company
    .Where(c => ids.contains(c.ID))
    .Include(country => country.Country)
```

Comment: I tried to find how should I solve it, but without expected result. This is what I was looking for, thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `companies` contains a list of objects with an `ID` property you want to compare to `Company.CompanyId`, your query should look like

```
int[] ids = companies.Select(cs => cs.ID).ToArray();
var companiesSummary = _context.Company
    .Where(c => ids.Contains(c.CompanyId))
    .Include(company => company.Country);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var matchingCompanies = companies.Where(c => companyIds.Contains(c.Id))
```

Make `companyIds` a `HashSet<T>` for an efficient `Contains`.

Comment: "Make companyIds a HashSet<T> for an efficient Contains.", why? This will be translated to SQL, it makes absolutely no difference what's the type of `companyIds`

Comment: The question does not say it will be converted to SQL, but thanks for the downvote

Comment: The use of `Include` is clearly from Entity Framework, just as the use of `_context.Company`.

Comment: The question never mentions entity Framework, and context is a very common variable name.